# Meaning of "également" in “a également déclaré”?

Tags: sens, adverbes, citations

I was reading the following summary for an article on *Le Monde*:

> **Xi appelle à une "renaissance de la nation chinoise" et au renforcement de l'armée**
>
> "Tous les soldats et officiers de l'Armée populaire et de la police militaire chinoises, guidés par le Parti, doivent être capables de remporter des combats", a également déclaré le nouveau président chinois.

I don't understand why the text at the end says "également déclaré" and not just "déclaré".  I thought that basically meant "also declared", as if the summary had previously mentioned someone else declaring the same thing, but I don't see it.  Is there some other meaning that "également" takes on in this context, or is it a typo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Le *également* fait référence à la citation de Xi présente dans titre, pas au fait qu'une autre personne a déclaré la même chose.

Comment: Ahhh maintenant je comprends.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

Le mot également peut avoir plusieurs significations dépendamment du contexte.

Comme tu l'as mentionné, parfois le mot également peut vouloir dire qu'une autre personne à déclaré/pensé la même chose, en gros fait la même action qu'une autre. Par exemple :

> Jean pense Y. Johanne le pense également.

Dans cette phrase, puisqu'on mentionne deux personne différentes, le mot vient préciser que la deuxième personne possède une similarité avec la première.

Prends par exemple un deuxième exemple (qui ressemble beaucoup à celui que tu as cité) :

> Jean pense Y. Il pense également X.

Dans ce deuxième exemple, les deux phrases se rapportent à la même personne. Mais on vient ajouter à cette même personne quelque chose d'autre, quelque chose de plus.

Le mot *également* se comporte exactement de la même façon que le mot « *also* » qui peut prendre plusieurs sens dépendamment du contexte.